# Do cars with automatic climate control still have a blower resistor?

Tags: renault, climate-control, clio

Our car is a Renault Clio 3 from 2008 with automatic climate control, with automatic temperature, like we set the temperature to 20 degrees Celsius and it'll adjust automatically to match. It has recently started having problems where the blowers wont work at any speed under any condition. Then a week will pass by and it'll start working perfectly again. I've been looking around and I've seen a broken blower resistor can do this to a car, but since we have automatic climate control, I'm unsure if the car even has a blower resistor.

The reason I'm unsure is because the climate control shows it speeding up the fans automatically, via the speed indicator on the display, so it obviously tries to control the fans based on some kind of temperature.

This is why I would like to know if cars with automatic climate control actually has a blower resistor, before I start poking around the car, so I don't waste my time.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Typically they use a FET on automatic HVAC. I'm not familiar with your make, but that's how Asian and US cars have been doing it for a while. Next time it happens monitor the ground side of the blower motor and it'll tell you if it's the fan or the control side of the circuit.

Comment: Related: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/46029/are-there-any-cars-where-the-blower-motor-is-controlled-by-switched-mode-power-s